# SVN checkout on mac using svn+ssh protocol

Tags: svn

I am checking in using public private key authentication. On windows its possible via putty but Smart svn on mac is not taking svn+ssh protocol, it again and again asks for the passphrase while via terminal, i am able to take the checkout and commit the code.

Any help is greatly appreciable.[image]